# How to locate warnings in Xcode storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a quick way to map from compiler warnings to the offending components in a storyboard?

I have, for example, a warning stating `Highlight tint color unsupported by this button type...` but I don't know how to map back to identify the relevant button in the storyboard?  The fix is simple once identified - is there a quick way to locate the button starting from the warning rather than having to inspect each custom button in my (quite extensive) storyboard?

Comment: For me, in Xcode 4.5, when the warning shows up in the "Issue Navigator" (on the left panel, click on the tab with the triangular button with an exclamation mark), I click on the warning and and it takes me to that element in question. I gather this is not the case for you?

Comment: No, it does for errors in the code base, but it doesn't take me to the relevant element inside the storyboard :(

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I cannot reproduce that problem and before I go further, I want to make sure it's not related to using an older version.

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right!  After a reboot it is now working as you suggest!  For the record, I am on Xcode 4.5.2. Following a reboot and restart of Xcode, when I now click on a warning, it pans the window to the right part of the storyboard and highlights the relevant widget.   Thank you! Could you possibly post an answer suggesting that I reboot so that I could accept it?!

Comment: Too often, when dealing with Xcode, that is the right answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally if you have an Interface Builder related warning, by clicking on that warning  [Issue Navigator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-issue_navigator/articles/viewing_issues_in_the_issue_navigator.html), Xcode should take you to Interface Builder and select that element in question for you. If that's not happening (and frankly, whenever Xcode stops behaving as it should), try quitting and restarting Xcode and, if that doesn't do it, rebooting your computer.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is facing similar problems (plus added problems like Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width etc) checkout this link.

**http://www.somegeekintn.com/blog/2014/10/tracking-down-storyboard-warnings/**

Comment: Thanks a lot, pal! 
The approach described in this article works even today. The bad part is that the original issue has still not yet been solved in XCode.